# OutOfMemory при повороте Bitmap

Tags: java, android

```
 public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            return bitmap;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
            matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
            matrix.setRotate(180);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            matrix.setRotate(90);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
            break;
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            matrix.setRotate(-90);
            break;
        default:
            return bitmap;
    }
try{
        Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        bitmap.recycle();
        return bmRotated;
}
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    textView.setText(e.getMessage());
    return null;
}

    }
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как справится с ошибкой OutOfMemory в этом методе?

Приложение при нажатии на кнопку фотографирует, поворачивает и сохраняет изображение на ImageView - первая фотография отображается нормально, при втором нажатии происходит OutOfMemory

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" в манифесте помогло, это конечно увеличивает процес очистки мусора  но для простенького приложения сойдет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все заключается в методе `.recycle()` и свойстве *mutable*. Свойство *mutable* означает, что `Bitmap` может быть изменен. Соответственно *immutable* означает, что `Bitmap` не может быть изменен, т.е. он *readOnly*.
Метод, который вы используете (`createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)`), от параметров и `Bitmap`-источника:

- если источник *immutable* и новый `Bitmap` будет являться точной копией исходника, то мы получим на выходе просто `Bitmap`-исходник. Т.е. это будет тот же `Bitmap` объект, и даже не его копия. И он останется *immutable*.
- если же источник mutable или новый Bitmap чем-то отличен от исходника, то мы получаем новый *mutable* `Bitmap` объект.

Для определения *mutable* состояния у `Bitmap` используется метод `isMutable`.
Уберите `.recycle()` и отдайте все на откуп **GC**.

Comment: но OutOfMemory по другой причине возникает